# Deploy with Active Jobs - active job ignores deployed code on next scheduled run

Tags: scheduled-apex, change-set, scheduled-job

I have an anonymous Apex scheduled  job that runs every three hours on the hour:

```
String cron = '0 00 07,10,13,16,19,22 * * ? 2015';  
MyScheduledDispatcher sd = new MyScheduledDispatcher();  
System.schedule('My Job 07-10-13-16-19-22h everyDay 2015',cron,sd);
```

Above job runs under user: `automatedJobUser`, System Admin profile

When I deploy via Changeset new code that is invoked by the schedulable class `MyScheduledDispatcher` (in my use case, a batchable class), I observe the following:

1. The new code is ignored on all future scheduled runs (!?!).
2. The new code is executed if I run the schedule under a different user (that is, launch a new schedule).
3. The new code is executed if I cancel the job and reschedule under `automatedJobuser`

### OBSERVATION: The scheduled job is bound to the last version of the code prior to creation of the schedule. Updating the code via a changeset has no effect

**Q1** - Is this because I'm using the Appleman pattern that doesn't have a compile-time reference to the changed-by-deployment batchable class - and SFDC doesn't think a runtime recompile is required?

**Q2** - Is there a better pattern to use given the code below so I can deploy at will and know that the next scheduled job instance will use the updated code?

I have Deployment options set as:
[image]

Yes, I can read and note `Enabling this option may cause Apex jobs to fail` but I interpreted this as "code would be swapped in in the middle of a series of batches and results would be unpredictable"

> It makes no sense to me that in one context, SFDC is executing prior
>   versions of the Apex code for running schedules while in all other
>   transactions, the new version of the code is used.

**Schedulable class defines an interface and `execute()` follows the Appleman pattern for decoupling the batchable from the schedulable:**

```
public MyScheduledDispatcher() {
    MyParms__c  p   = [select id, query__c, scope_Size__c from MyParms__c][0];      
}
public Interface IScheduleDispatched  { 
    void execute(SchedulableContext sc);
}
public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    Type schedHandlerType = Type.forName('MyBatchable'); // get Type for the desired ScheduleHandler class - this is the decoupling trick
    if(schedHandlerType != null) {
        IScheduleDispatched obj = (IScheduleDispatched)schedHandlerType.NewInstance(); // create instance of the ScheduleHandler but cast as interface IScheduleDispatched
        obj.execute(sc);                                                                    // invoke the execute() method on the interface object - which will start the batch 
    } 
}
```

**Batchable class (the one that was changed by deployment)** looks like:

```
public with sharing class MyBatchable 
        implements  Database.Batchable<Opportunity>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts, 
                    Iterable<Opportunity>, Iterator<Opportunity>,
                    MySchedulable.IScheduleDispatched {
 public MyBatchable() { // do stuff }

 public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) { // starts batch
    ID  batchProcessId  =  Database.executeBatch(this,this.scopeSize);
 }
 public Iterator<Opportunity> iterator() {return this;}
 public Boolean hasNext() { // do stuff }
 public Opportunity next() { // do stuff }
 public Iterable<Opportunity> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
     // do stuff }
 public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope) {
     // do useful stuff }
 public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) { // do stuff }
```

> Update:
>
> This is going to take some more experimentation with alternatives -- otherwise I'm going to have to delete and restart the schedule on every code change (not good, as I'll forget something some day)

Comment: If you upload a new version, and use Compile All Classes afterwards, does it still use the old version, or does that cause it to use new version?

Comment: @sfdcfox i'll try this but doesn't a PROD deploy recompile all classes in order to run the testmethods?

Comment: My understanding is that it does not. Go check Apex Classes, and create a view for "Is Valid equals false" to see how many classes you don't have compiled. Each class is stored in a cache and only compiled when using the Compile all classes feature or when deploying that specific class.

Comment: @sfdcfox - well, your suggestion worked - 0) job scheduled, (1) deploy via changeset new code in batchable class, (2) compile all classes, (3) schedule executes -- result is new code is included in scheduled job. Yea! That said, in my OP, the batchable class was getting deployed but not picked up on next schedule; the schedulable class was not being deployed.

Comment: @crop1645 - **GREAT** question crop. Thanks for alerting everyone to this issue. I did not even know it affected me :)

Comment: @cropredy is this still an issue? I think I am running into this but do not have access to prod so not sure of order things were done

Comment: @Eric don't have an answer as the org I built this on has been retired. I do know that a schedulable's constructor is not reinvoked on each job execution if on a recurring schedule.

Comment: So what is the answer for this?  After deployment (with the checkbox on), we need to click Compile All Classes, then the next scheduled run will pick up the new code? @Eric

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy - It was at the time yes. not sure about now

Answer (score 0):

In case you are considering the Force.com Migration tool for your deployments, you can have a look at [ForceFlow](https://github.com/eroispaziali/ForceFlow). It's a library I built on top of the metadata & tooling APIs to enhance automation around deployments. One of the features it has is clearing and resetting scheduled jobs.

Comment: you're welcome :)